# Composite key ID generator in Symfony

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm building a multi-tenant application using Symfony3, Doctrine and PostgreSQL.

I want that each entity have two primary keys: `tenantId` and `entityId`. This way, each tenant has each data with id's starting with 1.

So, user 'Xyz' from tentant 1 is http://example.com/users/1, and user 'Zzz' from tenant 2 is also http://example.com/users/1. The tenantId is stored in the session, so it's not represented in the URL (and yes, I know that this is incorrect RESTful).

I already know how to work with composite keys with Doctrine, adding @Id annotation to all the fields, but I don't know how to generate these id's.

Is there any automatic way to have this behavior, or I need to create a custom generator in Doctrine and find the `MAX(id) + 1` for the given entity, using a `WHERE tenantId = :TENANT_ID`?

Thanks for your help.

**Example of what I'm looking for:**

Tenants table:

tenantId | tenantName
1        | First company
2        | Second company

Users table:

tenantId | userId | userName
1        | 1      | Mr Foo Bar
1        | 2      | Mrs Bar Foo
2        | 1      | Mr John Doe
2        | 2      | Mrs Mary Doe

As you can see, the primary key of the users' table is a composite key (`tenantId`, `userId`). What I'm looking for is for a simple, automathic method to generate `userId`. In a table with only a PK, this method can be a simple generator or a SERIAL field, but as this is a composite PK, I need that the `userId` value depends on the `tenantId` field.

Comment: First of all, there's no such thing as "two primary keys", because they wouldn't be *primary* anymore. I guess you meant composite primary key. Anyway, what's the point of having two auto-incremented fields in the same table? They will have always the same value.

Comment: @dragoste: Yes, it's a composite primary key. And no, there won't be two auto-incremented fields. The only auto-incremented field would be `entityId`, because `tenantId` is a generic field for all the tables. The important thing is to have a generator for `entityId` that it's dependant to `entityId`.

Comment: Could you add some example data and/or pseudo code/queries to expose the issue?

Comment: @dragoste I've added some example data.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. So, it's a matter of RMDBS, not Doctrine itself. For example in MySQL it would just work as you wish if you create composite primary key and set auto_increment for the second field. Did you try that? I'm not sure how SERIAL type will work in PostgreSQL in such case.

Comment: Notice that he wants user id = 1 to be able to represent multiple users based on their tenant id.  So auto inc is out.  There is nothing built in to support this approach.  He will need his own custom id generator.  @mHouses - make sure you really need this functionality because this can quickly turn into a mess.  Just make user id unique and be done with it.